# Theorem relating with uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis

I read the following theorem from Rudin's book. I understand it's proof but I could not understand the meaning of this theorem.
[image]

I would be really grateful to anyone who will explain me.

By the way. Am I true that $f_n:X\to\mathbb{R}$? where $X$ some metric space.

Comment: Can you say more about what it is that you don't understand?

Comment: @TimRaczkowski, What this theorem tell us about?

Comment: If you have a uniformly convergent sequence of functions and a limit point then you can use them to construct a convergent sequence. and get the limit of that sequence from $f$.

Comment: I think that many of us would prefer to see this as saying $$\lim_{t\to x} \lim_{n\to \infty} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \lim_{t\to x} $$  which is what 18th century mathematicians invoked whenever they needed it.  "Uniform convergence" justifies it here, and sometimes you can get away with the maneuver in other situations too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about the case where $f_n$ are continuous. In that case, you can extend $f_n$ and $f$ to the closure of $E$ by continuity, and the numbers $A_n$ are just $f_n(x)$, by continuity. In that case the theorem says that you can extend the set of points where $f_n$ converges to $f$ to include also the limit points of the given set $E$. That is, $f_n(x)$ will converge to $f(x)$ as $n\to\infty$ whenever $x$ is a limit point. In other words, uniform convergence on $E$ will imply convergence on the closure, too.

In the general case, where $f_n$ are not necessarily continuous, it cannot be asserted that the numbers $A_n$ are equal to $f_n(x)$, so the meaning of the theorem is somewhat less tangible in this case. I believe Rudin proved it in this general setting just because he could do so.

Comment: What you've said is actually connected in a nice way to the original statement, because of the following simple result: given $f$ (maybe continuous, maybe not), the function $g(x)$ defined to be $f(x)$ if $x$ is not a limit point and $\lim_{t \to x} f(t)$ if $x$ is a limit point, is continuous (provided $g$ is well-defined, i.e. $\lim_{t \to x} f(t)$ exists at each limit point of the domain).

Comment: I have one question. If $f_n$ are continuous then $\lim \limits_{t\to x}f_n(t)=f_n(x)$ i.e. you extended $f_n$ to the closure of $E$. The result of theorem is $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)=\lim \limits_{t\to x}f(t)$. But how you extended $f$ to point $x$? We don't know does $x\in E$ or not?